# Allocating Memory beforehand for a C++ application

Tags: c++

I am developing a C++ application with Qt; involving tremendous number crunching. A large amount of dynamic memory is required for the entire operation. However the requirement is variable depending on a variable set by the user.

In resource monitor I can see that the *Commit memory* (memory allocated by OS for the exe) keeps on increasing with time as my program creates arrays in dynamic memory. So if I let Windows know beforehand that my exe will use **X MB** of memory, will this result in improved performance? If yes then how do I do this?

Comment: Have you considered reusing some of the allocated arrays.. or perhaps resusing them as vectors

Comment: Have you actually run a profiler on your application, to see where it is spending time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of memory allocations and cpu-intensive process that runs together, you might consider restructuring your program to use some memory pools.

The idea behind memory pool is that you allocate a pool of resources that you will probably need when processing beings, (maps, vectors, or any objects you happen to **new** very often), and the time you need a new object, you take the first available one from the pool, reset and use it, and when you are done with it you put it back into the pool so that it can be used again later.

This pattern can happen to be faster than continuously use new and delete, but only if your program intensively uses dynamic allocations while it is doing, for example, a minmax search over a huge tree, or something as intensive as that.

Comment: try using VerySleepy to recognize these kinds of performance issues. It will show you very quickly if your application is spending a lot of time on the new and delete operations.

Comment: @Lake as you have mentioned, My arrays are created initially in a pool & then used as & when required. I was concerned about the step where arrays are dynamically allocated by new operator. Since the size is large & multiple arrays are required, I wanted to know a way to tell Windows that I am allocating this X amount of memory so that it will not have to allocate each time I am creating a new array.

Answer (score 1):

> So if I let Windows know beforehand that my exe will use X MB of memory, will this result in improved performance? If yes then how do I do this?

I don't think so. The memory your app operates on is virtual and you don't really have a good control on how Windows actually allocates/maps physical memory onto virtual.

But you can try allocating the required amount of memory upfront and then use it as a pool for custom allocators. It may result in some performance hit however.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a large alloc and delete.

```
char *ptr = new char[50*1024*1024L];
delete[] *ptr;
```

I doubt if there is going to be any performance difference.

Comment: That probably won't help, because Windows (like other modern OS's) does "lazy" allocation of physical memory. This means that if you allocate 50MB and don't use any of it, the OS will just mark up 50MB of virtual space "in use", but not actually assign any physical memory to this lump of memory. When the memory gets to be actually used (read from or written to), the OS will at that point assign physical memory to it. This comes about because OS's assume that programmers will allocate large buffers for various purposes, and then not use all of it...

Comment: The new/malloc call OS system calls to get memory. The only advantage of this new+delete is that after this, there no more OS calls to get memory, unless dynamic memory requirement go beyond 50MB. This _does_ have a very tiny performance difference.

Comment: It MAY have a tiny effect, yes. But actually populating the pages will still happen at a later stage, and at least in glibc's malloc implementation, large chunks of allocation is calling mmap, and if the whole block used by mmap is then freed, it is immediately released back to the OS (and I expect that the gnu std C++ library also does this, either by calling the underlying malloc functions or implementing a similar scheme, but I haven't looked at how `new` is actually implemented). If you know any different, let me know.

Comment: I clearly stated my doubt of this approach in my answer. The OP wanted a way to tell runtime/OS that the program is going to need so much of memory, and this is the only portable way of doing it. I've observed in ancient unix systems, that this improved performance, and also understand this observation may not be be valid with today's systems. The reason can be, that malloc only has 1 pool instead of 100's of pools, leading to lesser time to search free space and also  lesser fragmentation , leading to lesser page faults etc.. .. memory profiling and how it impact performance is a hard problem